# How can I change a lot of parameters to Real?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Because of some formulas with Conjugate in a notebook, I have to tell mathematica to change a lot of parameters to Real! 
I know that I can use Refine with Element or Assumptions:

```
Refine[k + x + g, Element[x | k | g, Reals]]
```

or

```
Refine[%, Assumptions -> {x, k, g} \[Element] Reals]
```

, But it's useful for a few parameters not a lot!

For Example I'd like to define:

```
Ki,j & i{1 to 20} , j{1 to 20}
```

in Reals. Is there any function to define it without telling mathematica one by one?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Start by not using parameters with subscripts. They look pretty, but they are a pain to deal with. Rename the variables: e.g. use `bi` instead of `Subscript[b,i]`. Another tip: don't use uppercase single letter variable names: they can conflict with built-in symbols. For instance, `K` is already an existing symbol (try and execute `?K`).

Comment: You can specify a domain for some functions.  There are `Cases`, `Variables` and other functions that might be useful in extracting the parameters from your code. --  As written currently, this question is a bit too broad.  Can you provide a minimal working example, that would be typical of the problem that concerns you?

Comment: For Example I'd like to define Ki,j & i{1 to 20} & j{1 to 20} in Reals. Is there any function to define it without telling mathematica one by one?

Comment: Please add that information to the question and supply some examples to avoid unnecessary effort. General advice: avoid subscripts. They are a big source of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by `Ki,j` but perhaps this

```
vars = ToExpression@
   Flatten@Table["K" <> ToString[i] <> "$" <> ToString[j], {i, 20}, {j, 20}];
```

or this

```
vars = Flatten@Table[k[i, j], {i, 20}, {j, 20}];
```

Then one can use it thus:

```
Assuming[vars ∈ Reals,
 Refine[
   Apply[
    Times,
    Sqrt[vars ^ RandomInteger[4, Length[vars]]]
    ]] /. p_Power :> Simplify[p]
 ]
(* large expression with Sqrt[x^2] simplified to Abs[x] etc. *)
```